# I got troubles installing xubuntu in my netbook dell

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu

I have troubles installing the xubuntu 12.10 version. I'm trying to install it from a USB containing an ISO image of xubuntu because my netbook does not have a CD/DVD burner, I've also used YUMI to create a booteable USB, but it doesn't work properly, the message the screen shows is the next:

**BusyBox v1.19.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.19.3-7ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system**

I wonder if you guys would mind helping me to solve this problem.

I get stuck on this step, and it happens the same when I try to install Ubuntu 8.10

I need your help guys, I am beginner in these topics about Ubuntu and other distros.

Comment: try other tools to create live usb. http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/,  http://www.linuxliveusb.com/, http://www.aligunduz.org/FUSBi/, or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_to_create_Live_USB_systems

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the ISO file, check that the md5sum (hash) of the ISO file matches the md5sum of the file as listed on the download site. If the values do not match, download the file again. The md5sum can be checked from the command-line in GNU/Linux with the `md5sum` command or with the [HashTab](http://implbits.com/HashTab.aspx) program in Windows or MacOS.

If the problem persists, try using a different USB flash drive. The ISO can be copied to a USB flash drive from a variety of operating systems with the [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) program.